# SQLAlchemy - defining a foreign key relationship in a different database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy declarative and python2.7 to read asset information from an existing database. The database uses a number of foreign keys for constant values. Many of the foreign keys exist on a different database.

How can I specify a foreign key relationship where the data exists on a separate database?

I've tried to use two separate Base classes, with the models inheriting from them separately.

I've also looked into specifying the primaryjoin keyword in relationship, but I've been unable to understand how it would be done in this case.

I think the problem is that I can only bind one engine to a session object. I can't see any way to ask sqlalchemy to use a different engine when making a query on a nested foreign key item.

```
OrgBase = declarative_base()
CommonBase = declarative_base()

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(sql_user, sql_pass, sql_host, org_db, common_host, common)
        self.engine = create_engine("{type}://{user}:{password}@{url}/{name}".format(type=db_type,
                                                                                     user=sql_user,
                                                                                     password=sql_pass,
                                                                                     url=sql_host,
                                                                                     name=org_db))

        self.engine_common = create_engine("{type}://{user}:{password}@{url}/{name}".format(type=db_type,
                                                                                     user=sql_user,
                                                                                     password=sql_pass,
                                                                                     url=common_host,
                                                                                     name="common"))

        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()
        OrgBase.metadata.bind = self.engine
        CommonBase.metadata.bind = self.engine_common
```

models.py:

```
class FrameRate(CommonBase):
    __tablename__ = 'content_frame_rates'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}


class VideoAsset(OrgBase):
    __tablename__ = 'content_video_files'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    frame_rate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('content_frame_rates.frame_rate_id'))
    frame_rate = relationship(FrameRate, foreign_keys=[frame_rate_id])
```

Error with this code:

`NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'content_video_files.frame_rate_id' could not find table 'content_frame_rates' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'frame_rate_id'`

if I run:

`asset = self.session.query(self.VideoAsset).filter_by(uuid=asset_uuid).first()`

My hope is that the VideoAsset model can nest frame_rate properly, finding the value on the separate database.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more information. What DBMS(s) are you using? Are all your DB using the same DBMS? Are they on the same server? Please share (relevant parts of) the existing schema with foreign key references to separate DBs.

Comment: Both databases are using mysql. Unfortunately they are on different hosts. frame_rate_id is the primary key on table content_frame_rates in the common database and frame_rate_id is the foreign key on table content_video_files on the other database.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I didn't think MySQL supported foreign key constraints spanning different hosts.

Comment: You might have to excuse my poor use of terminology as I'm still in the learning process about databases. I only really need to lookup data with a primary key in another database/table. My hope is that I can somehow specify this in the models classes for much cleaner code, but I could just run two queries one after the other and save the retrieved data to each attribute. More or less do the nesting manually instead of automatically. If this is the best way to go I'll look at refactoring things.